# IntelliJ template dialog list

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created a code template in IntelliJ IDEA that creates a new class for me.
The problem is, as far as I understood, IntelliJ by default supports only simple strings as variables in the dialog box.

How can I create not a simple string line but a drop-down list with my predefined values? See the example on the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is not supported for File/Code Templates. Feel free to raise a new feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA . You can consider creating a custom plugin that implements a similar logic to "New GUI Form" dialog. See https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/0e2aa4030ee763c9b0c828f0b5119f4cdcc66f35/plugins/ui-designer/src/com/intellij/uiDesigner and https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/welcome.html

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Hey Egor! I have a one more question regarding file templates. Can I import other developer's templates? Something like "Create File Template from this file" or "Mark Directory as Templates"?
For now, I just copy the contents of someone else's template and create my own one based on this, which is not very convenient.